# Error en buscador (fechas)

Tags: php, date

Realizo un sistema de tickets que tiene un modulo de reportes generales en lo que pretendo que se busquen por fechas **created_at** (fecha de inicio) y **updated_at** (fecha de modificación) junto con los campos:

**estatus_id** (puede ser abierto o cerrado)

**priority_id**  (prioridad, puede ser alta, baja o media)

**kind_id**  (tipo, puede ser soporte o reporte).

El problema que tengo es que selecciono las fechas (existen en mis registros dentro de mi BD) junto con los otros campos y siempre sale el mensaje que no hay tickets disponibles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estructura de BD**

```
id           Primaria   int(11) 
process_1               varchar(500)
process_2               varchar(500)
updated_at              datetime
created_at              datetime
kind_id       Índice    int(11)
user_id       Índice    int(11) 
priority_id   Índice    int(11) 
area_id       Índice    int(11) 
estatus_id    Índice    int(11)
final_id      Índice    int(11) 
project_id    Índice    int(11)
```

Saludos.

**CÓDIGO PHP**

```html
<?php
    $users= array();
    if((isset($_GET["estatus_id"]) && isset($_GET["kind_id"])  && isset($_GET["priority_id"]) && isset($_GET["created_at"]) && isset($_GET["updated_at"]) ) && ($_GET["estatus_id"]!="" ||$_GET["kind_id"]!="" || $_GET["priority_id"]!="" || ($_GET["created_at"]!="" && $_GET["updated_at"]!="") ) ) {
    $sql = "select * from ticket where ";
    if($_GET["estatus_id"]!=""){
        $sql .= " estatus_id = ".$_GET["estatus_id"];
    }

    if($_GET["kind_id"]!=""){
    if($_GET["estatus_id"]!=""){
        $sql .= " and ";
    }
        $sql .= " kind_id = ".$_GET["kind_id"];
    }



    if($_GET["priority_id"]!=""){
    if($_GET["estatus_id"]!=""||$_GET["project_id"]!=""||$_GET["kind_id"]!=""){
        $sql .= " and ";
    }

        $sql .= " priority_id = ".$_GET["priority_id"];
    }



    if($_GET["created_at"]!="" && $_GET["updated_at"]){
    if($_GET["estatus_id"]!=""||$_GET["project_id"]!="" ||$_GET["priority_id"]!="" ||$_GET["kind_id"]!="" ){
        $sql .= " and ";
    }

        $sql .= " ( date_at >= \"".$_GET["created_at"]."\" and date_at <= \"".$_GET["updated_at"]."\" ) ";
    }

            $users = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

}else{
            $users = mysqli_query($con, "select * from ticket order by created_at desc");

    }

if(@mysqli_num_rows($users)>0){
    // si hay reportes
    $_SESSION["report_data"] = $users;
?>
```

Comment: Carlos ¿podrías identar mejor el código, está muy a la derecha y encima lo pones en un codesnippet. Es complicado de analizar así. Y no uses codesnippet para código que no se puede probar aquí, no tiene ninguna utilidad y dificulta analizar el problema. De paso, muestra un `var_dump($_GET);` para ver cómo están llegando los datos al servidor, puede que sea un problema de formato de fechas. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano Buenos días, ya esta editado el código por Macaroni, realice el var_drum pero no me muestra nada.

Comment: Carlos, hay dos depuraciones importantes que debes hacer: 1ª mostrar en pantalla lo que hay en el GET, puedes hacerlo con **`var_dump($_GET);`**  2ª mostrar en pantalla el valor de `$sql`, puedes hacerlo con **`echo $sql;`** Intenta eso y ponlo en la pregunta editándola. En el código hay demasiadas cosas que no se pueden reproducir por tanto debes depurarlas tú y de paso lo tomas como práctica: **cuando algo no funcione, muéstralo para analizarlo**. A la espera de esos datos...

Comment: Si el `var_dump` no muestra nada debes revisar el formulario o el medio desde el que envías los datos, o revisar si estás apuntando al archivo correcto que recibe los datos.